# find table records which are not present in other two table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables T1, T2 and T3. T3 has all the record which T1 and T2 have along with some additional record. I want to find out additional rows

### T1

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe |
| 2 | Patrick |

### T2

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | Tom |
| 4 | Greg |

### T3

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe |
| 2 | Patrick |
| 3 | Tom |
| 4 | Greg |
| 5 | Wei |
| 6 | Sam |

### Expected Result

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | Wei |
| 6 | Sam |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM T3
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE T3.ID=T1.ID) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE T3.ID=T2.ID)
```

Comment: With indexes on `ID` in the subtables, this is probably the best performing solution.  More importantly, it does not remove duplicates in `T3` -- nor incur overhead for doing so -- so I think this should be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT A.ID,A.NAME FROM T3 AS A
   MINUS --EXCEPT 
 (
     SELECT B.ID, B.NAME FROM T1 AS B
       UNION ALL
     SELECT C.ID,C.NAME FROM T2 AS C
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--=> t3 - t2 - t1

SELECT * FROM T3
MINUS
SELECT * FROM T1
MINUS
SELECT * FROM T2
```